# Calculate the sum of the acquisition price of works of art for each year

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Need some help with this question on SQL query based on the following table (TRANSACTION) attributes. Appreciate the help.

TRANSACTIONID
DATEACQUIRED
ACQUISITIONPRICE
DATESOLD
ASKINGPRICE
SALESPRICE
CUSTOMERID
WORKID

Calculate the sum of the acquisition price of works of art for each year (for example, if there were two works of art purchased for $1500 and $1000 in 2007, and one work of art purchased for $500 in 2008, then the sums would be $2500 and $500, for 2007 and 2008 respectively). The result table should show year and sum of acquisition price.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? Please don't use incorrect tags.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL that would be:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEACQUIRED), SUM(ACQUISITIONPRICE) FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(DATEACQUIRED)
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEACQUIRED), SUM(ACQUISITIONPRICE) FROM table GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEACQUIRED)
```

assuming DATEACQUIRED is actually a full date.

Comment: yah.. i tried the same too.. using YEAR() but then it gives me a error message as below. not sure whether does it got to do with the date. example of the date: 17/11/07

ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Try: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEACQUIRED)` instead of `YEAR(DATEACQUIRED)`. Does that work?

Comment: yes, this is what i have now. but it give me a few rows of years and acquisition price. what i am looking for is one row of each individual year and the total acquisition price for that year.. e.g 2007 - totalacquisitionprice, 2008 - total acquisitionprice etc

Comment: And you are grouping by the extract? e.g. `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEACQUIRED), SUM(ACQUISITIONPRICE) FROM table GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEACQUIRED)`

Comment: Glad to hear! Updated original answer to reflect this.